# Determine the last 2 snapshot dates and select the items that have the current snapshot date AND also they have a previous snapshot date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My table looks like this:

```
ID  snapshotDate    Item    ItemCode
--  ------------   -----      -----
1   2015-11-01     Item1         11
2   2016-04-01     Item2         22 
3   2016-04-01     Item3         33
4   2016-06-01     Item4         44
5   2016-09-01     Item3         33
6   2016-08-01     Item5         55
7   2016-09-01     Item4         44
8   2017-01-10     Item6         66 
9   2017-01-10     Item4         44
```

First I want to determine the last 2 snapshot dates, the result should be:

> 2016-09-01   -- I am going to call this one (Current snapshot date)
>   2017-01-10   -- I am going to call this one (Previous snapshot date)

And then I would like to select the items that have the current snapshot date AND also they have a previous snapshot date. It should look like:

```
ID  snapshotDate   Item       ItemCode
--  ------------   -----      -----
7   2016-09-01     Item4      44
9   2017-01-10     Item4      44
```

Comment: No question. No research. No attempt. Just a shout-out to the Code-4-U community?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
declare @curr date, @prev date

select @curr = max(snapshotdate), @prev = min(snapshotdate)
from
(
    select distinct top 2 snapshotdate from Table1 order by snapshotdate desc
) X

select * from Table1 
where snapshotdate in (@curr, @prev)
and item in (
    -- select items that have row in both snapshotdates
    select item from Table1
    where snapshotdate in (@curr, @prev)
    group by item
    having count(*) = 2
)
```

Your example isn't correct though, only Item4 has row in latest and previous snapshot.